# Having trouble deploying simple web app in Jetty

Tags: java, jetty

I am using Jetty to write a simple server.

SimpleServer.java:

```
public class SimpleServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(new ServerHandler());
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }   

}
```

ServerHandler.java:

```
public class ServerHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    }
}
```

I use maven to package the files up into a war file and then throw them in the jetty/webapps directory.  I have the war file named root.war, so that means the context is at localhost:8080/.  But when I access it, I get the following error in the browser:

```
HTTP ERROR 503

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
```

In the console, I get a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.  This project works and runs in IntelliJ.  It's only when I put it in the jetty/webapps folder that I get errors.

Comment: Post your web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example codebase is written using the Jetty [`Handler`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler.html) API.

A WAR file expects the [Servlet API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html), not the Jetty Handler API.

If you want to continue using the Jetty `Handler` API, then you'll be staying with `embedded-jetty` and doing everything without a WAR file.

If you want a WAR file, then you'll have to not use the Jetty `Handler` API.

Migrate your code to using the Servlet API, and add a reference to it in your Web Descriptor (`WEB-INF/web.xml`).  That will produce a proper WAR file that can be deployed.

```java
public class ServerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    }
}
```

Note: You can optionally, you can use the [Servlet API Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/package-summary.html) instead of the `WEB-INF/web.xml`, but know that you'll want your `${jetty.base}` instance directory configured to have the `annotations` module enabled.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. I didn't pick this up when going through the eclipse documentation.